# split comma seperated column into many pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 columns with string values separated by comma. I want to split the column into required columns. For example I have two columns with entries (strings) below.

```
col1            col2
a,b,c,d         e,f,g,h,i
c,d             h,i
```

My required cols are:

```
cola    colb    colc   cold    cole    colf    colg    colh    coli
a        b        c      d       e       f       g       h       i
                  c      d                               h       i
```

I can split the columns and I have done coding, but I don't know how to do it the above way.
Secondly, I want to split multiple column in one line code.

```
df1 = df2['col1'].str.split(',' , expand=True) # This only split one column col1.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) for each column and concatenate the result with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = (pd
 .concat({k: df[k].str.get_dummies(sep=',') for k in df.columns}, axis=1)
 .pipe(lambda d: d.mul(d.columns.get_level_values(1))
                  .set_axis(map('_'.join, d.columns), axis=1)
      )
)
```

output:

```
  col1_a col1_b col1_c col1_d col2_e col2_f col2_g col2_h col2_i
0      a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h      i
1                    c      d                           h      i
```